# Facebook publish_actions to timeline denied

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook denied the publish_actions permission because we auto-populated the message, meaning we didn't allow users to type message.  We post our generic message.  I've seen there are apps that are allowed to auto-populate the message i.e. game apps that post scores to user's timeline.  My question is, can you still auto-populate the message with newly created apps? If so, what steps do we need to take.  I've read around and found that Facebook policy changed, and if your app was created prior to policy changing, you lucked out and are allowed to auto-populate messages.  Wanted to get clarity on this if anyone knows.

Comment: Nope. No apps are allowed to prefill the message and it been several years since that was allowed. If you know any apps that does it please send me the names and I forward it to Developer Operations.

Comment: Let users share a link instead. Via Open Graph meta tags under the URL you can specify title, description and thumbnail – and you can use that to transport the information.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation WizKid and thanks for the suggestion CBroe.